# How to make SQL count a specific row when another specific row has a certain element

Tags: sql, sql-server

Table #1

```
ID     Name    Category
--------------------------------------
1      WASD     cat1
2      QWER     cat1
3      QWER     cat1
4      WASD     cat2
5      WASD     cat2
6      WASD     cat2
```

I want to be able to take `Name` and `Category` and count how many times  `cat1` & `cat2` are presented within the table. But they both must be corresponding with `WASD` in the `name` row.

For example, the output I want with this is:

```
Cat1Amount    Cat2Amount
    1             3
```

I want this output because `Cat1` only appears once due to the other 2 `cat1's` being alongside `QWER`. And `cat2` appears 3 times as WASD is alongside `cat2` 3 times.

I am currently using this as my Query:

```
SELECT 
    Cat1Amount = SUM(CASE WHEN Category='cat1' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
    Cat2Amount = SUM(CASE WHEN Category='cat2' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 
FROM 
    dbo.Example
```

The issue with this is it does show me how many times `cat1` and `cat2` appear within the table but not how many times they each appear when `WASD` is present.

Comment: Did you try adding `SELECT Name, ...` and `GROUP BY Name`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `where` clause & do aggregation :

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN Category = 'cat1' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END), 
       SUM(CASE WHEN Category = 'cat2' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 
FROM dbo.Example e
WHERE Name = 'WASD';
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also do

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN Category = 'cat1' AND Name = 'WASD' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) Cat1Amount, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN Category = 'cat2' AND Name = 'WASD'  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) Cat2Amount 
FROM Tbl
```

Comment: this was my preferred method of doing aggregates off fact/dim style till code was consumed by ssas mdx cube.

Answer (score 0):

Try below

```
SELECT name,count(CASE WHEN Category = 'cat1' THEN 1 end) as cat1amount, 
       count(CASE WHEN Category = 'cat2' THEN 1 END) as cat2amount
FROM dbo.Example e
WHERE Name = 'WASD'
group by name
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COUNT(Category)
FROM table_name
WHERE name = 'WASD' category = 'cat1';

SELECT COUNT(Category)
FROM table_name
WHERE name = 'WASD' category = 'cat2';
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select Category, count(ID) as counted
From Table#1 a
where a.Name = 'WASD'
Group by Category
```

The result will be:

Category counted

cat1           1

cat2     3